# Install QGIS 3 and QGIS 2.0 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-3, qgis-2.18, ubuntugis

I have successfully installed  QGIS-3 on my ubuntu 18.04. I want to install QGIS-2 as well along with QGSI-3. How can i install QGIS-2.18 as well. So that QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 both would be running on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You have to compile them yourself, or put one of them in a VirtualBox. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155847/installing-two-versions-of-qgis-in-ubuntu and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71208/how-to-install-two-versions-of-qgis-on-ubuntu-12-04 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52409/how-to-setup-qgis-master-and-stable-in-parallel-on-one-linux-system

Comment: Or use the conda-forge channel to install QGIS2

Comment: I can't figure out, why this question is marked duplicate.

Comment: Because there are still the same reasons and solutions to get two versions of QGIS running in parallel on the same Ubuntu computer.

Comment: You can install QGIS from NextGIS PPA (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287941/9904

Comment: @AnreJ I think that not very extensive answer from 2013 on that matter does  justify a duplicate. The "solution" with compiling is also no real solution: Lot of work to get into the matter, always the danger to crash your system etc.. The "solution" with a VitualBox is no solution: Lots of hazzle with setting up network connections, paths are different and not interchangeable anymore, less performance etc etc.

Comment: @Luke what is conda-forge, how does it work and which version will be installed?

Comment: @Dmitry Baryshnikov This looks like an easy fix, provided that this repository is maintained as well as the original one. It would be nice if an answer would be formed out of all these suggestions. Killing this thread because it's a duplicate will help no one, because things evolve and new solutions might become available, so its definately NO duplicate!

Comment: Install [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html). `conda create -c conda-forge -n qgis2 qgis=2` `source activate qgis2` `qgis`

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov Installing QGIS3 after installing NextGIS removes NextGIS from my Computer. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Luke Sorry for asking again. As I'm completely not familiar with all this, which flavor is the recommend one for QGIS: Miniconda or Anaconda?

Comment: Installing QGIS via Anaconda works with conda create -c conda-forge -n qgis2 qgis=2. But there are several hickups with paths i think. E.g. the GUI has no buttons

Comment: @BerndV. I reproduced this. Just fix error with breaks statement for `python-qgis` package. Will updated soon. Just install again via `sudo apt install ngqgis` tomorrow.